# Issue with emulator resolution in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

here is the thing , after i installed android studio version 1.0.2 , created my Android Virtual Device and the started it i can not see the font , it is extremely small , what should I do

[image]

here is my manifest

```
                 <activity
                  android:name=".Splash"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" >
                 <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                 </intent-filter>
                 </activity>
                <activity
                android:name=".MyActivity"
                android:label="@string/hello_world"
                 >
              <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.example.hp.app2.MyActivity" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               </intent-filter>
               </activity>
              <activity
              android:name=".Menu"
              android:label="@string/hello_world"
            >
             <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.hp.app2.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
             </activity>
             <activity
             android:name=".textPlay"
             android:label="@string/hello_world"
                  >

             </activity>
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're just using a very large screen on the emulator, which is then sized down to fit on your screen. Try creating a new emulator instance with a smaller resolution? This seriously looks like xxxhdpi to me.

Comment: please reduce your emulator resolution.

Comment: that was the problem , thank you guys , it was really disturbing

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug of Android.
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=608

In my case I convert myFont.ttf to .ttx and again to .ttf